# Goodbye to 2020

Tags: crosswords

[image]

### ACROSS

**1.** *(with 5 across)* what many wore in 2020
**5.** *see 1 across*
**10.** a Canadien
**13.** Warwickshire river
**14.** a rock, perhaps
**15.** an airline *(2 words)*
**17.** tirade
**18.** Reagan's "Just ___" *(2 words)*
**19.** hipbones
**20.** mammalian heat
**22.** fermented milks
**24.** what many became in 2020
**26.** Fire Emblem herons
**27.** missile storehouse
**28.** desire
**29.** banish
**32.** what many dressed as for in 2020
**34.** what many used in 2020
**38.** what many did in 2020: *abbr.*
**39.** counterpart to 16 down
**40.** red-pill guy
**41.** *(with 43 across)* what many made in 2020
**43.** *(see 41 across)*
**45.** Evelyn, a nurse who died of COVID in 2020
**46.** he had X Æ A-12 in 2020
**48.** apiece
**50.** a split constellation
**53.** a liqueur *(2 words)*
**57.** a rare paper in 2020
**58.** a common parasite type in 2020
**59.** queen of jazz
**60.** affected
**64.** mathematician known for his theorem on antipodes
**65.** demeanor
**66.** a brand of embroidery thread
**67.** nota ___
**68.** a monitor type: *abbr.*
**69.** Greene who died in 2020
**70.** boatswain of fiction

### DOWN

**1.** transit payments
**2.** antivirus manufacturer
**3.** PTE1000
**4.** hand over
**5.** some thrushes
**6.** drunk ___ lord *(2 words)*
**7.** Rocky portrayer
**8.** Spears who died in 2020
**9.** intensify *(2 words)*
**10.** violinist Jascha
**11.** betting everything *(2 words)*
**12.** mathematician known for his "category theorem"
**16.** colleen
**21.** *E. coli*, often
**23.** triage centers: *abbr.*
**25.** certain deodorants *(2 words)*
**26.** taunts, in sports
**29.** cries of pain
**30.** an insect, perhaps: *abbr.*
**31.** solitary-confinement area: *abbr.*
**33.** hydration for Henri
**35.** Ode ___ Grecian Urn *(2 words)*
**36.** Whistle ___ the Lave o'it
**37.** extensible VR
**42.** move to a bigger pot, e.g.
**43.** you'd rather remain in ignorance *(2 words)*
**44.** at peace
**45.** sortsa angels
**47.** Brodie who died in 2020
**49.** dove sound
**50.** pear handle
**51.** of the wind
**52.** someone who does 9 down
**54.** android
**55.** vapid
**56.** someone christened
**61.** Yorkshire river
**62.** 15 across dest.
**63.** brew suffix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue answers (and explanations where necessary):

> [image]